# Repetition of the same results consecutif

Tags: python, django

I need to check if I have repetition 4 times the same value for "PCR POS/Neg" consecutive, 3 times in my "output_df".

How i can do it ?

```
def results1(file1,file2):

    results_list = defaultdict(list)
    names_loc = file2
    listing_file = pd.read_excel(file1, index_col=None)
    headers = ['Vector Name', 'Date and Time', 'Test ID', 'PCR POS/Neg']
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

    with open(names_loc, "r") as fp:
        for line in fp.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip("\\\n")
            full_name = line.split(',')
            sample_name = full_name[0].split('_mean')
          
    output_df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(output_df['Date and Time'])
```

Comment: Do you want only to print how many 4 consecutive values  in output_df ['PCR POS/Neg']?

Comment: i need to check if i have 4 times in my file, 3 consecutives identics values , if yes so i will receive a message ERROR

Comment: You can use my answer below

Comment: example: A A A B B A A A B A A A C A A A

Comment: Ok, now, your problem is clear. How many values does this column have only A, B,C?

Comment: if i am using your answer , it is for one time 3 consecutives identic values , yes ?

Comment: No, it is for 4 consecutive numbers, but they should be numbers.

Comment: I updated the solution based on your recent info. They are alphabets, not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value' : ['A','A','A','A', 'B','B','C','C','C','B','B']})

df['new'] = df["value"].apply(lambda x: ord(x))
np.floor(df["new"].diff().eq(0).sum()/3)
```